# Azure DevOps - Github status checks

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have n+ github repositories that I would like to connect to 2 separate Azure DevOps pipelines.

- I do not want to use azure-pipelines.yaml per repo as it would be the same for all of them. In case of any changes I would prefer to change in a single repo then in n+ of them.
- My goal is to have a github status checks for commits and PRs for all my n+ repos.
- The pipelines themselves are hosted in github (if that makes any difference).

My current setup to trigger on push is to use `resources` in following manner:

```
resources: 
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    name: woohoo/validation1
    trigger: none  # to avoid triggering the build for pipeline itself
  - repository: repo1
    type: githubenterprise
    name: woohoo/repo1
    endpoint: myendpoint
    trigger:  
      branches:
        include:
         - test/*
    pr: 
     branches:
      include:
       - '*' 
  - repository: repo2
    type: githubenterprise
    name: woohoo/repo2
    endpoint: myendpoint
    trigger:  
      branches:
        include:
         - test/*
    pr: 
     branches:
      include:
       - '*' 
  ...
```

This works well for triggering the builds and run them correctly but status checks are still missing. Also, I do not see the pipeline when editing *Branch protection rule* in *Require status checks to pass before merging section*.

I suspect that I'm missing some triggers/hooks configuration, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found only one solution for this kind of problem. It is a direct GitHub API call based on [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-status)

```
curl \
   -X POST \
   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
   -u {my-name}:{my-PAT} \
   https://api.github.com/repos/{my-org}/{my-repo}/statuses/{commit-sha} \
   -d '{"state":"success", "description": "test status change"}'
```

1. {my-PAT} is [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), the scope for it has to be 'repo:state' (or more)
2. {commit-sha} should be able to find at runtime, look to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource) with examples for pipeline/container. My case is pipeline resource (not repository):

   resources.pipeline.[Alias].sourceBranch

   resources.pipeline.[Alias].sourceCommit
3. I suppose all other {my-*} values are clear.

After the success request, I found the line with the title `default` in the list of available status checks. Based on [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-status) it can be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I've moved along from that project so can't verify but changing/creating those checks with api calls seems like a legit solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use the GitHub Status check,
first, create a pipeline for the repository and build it at least once so that its status is posted to GitHub, thereby making GitHub aware of the pipeline's name.
Next, follow GitHub's documentation for configuring protected branches in the repository's settings.
You can follow this doc: [Protected branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#protected-branches)
And if you want to use the trigger settings, we recommend you change your yaml to this:

```
 - repository: repo1
    type: githubenterprise
    name: woohoo/repo1
    endpoint: myendpoint
    trigger:  
      branches:
        include:
         - test/*
    pr: 
     branches:
      include:
       - '*'
```

Comment: _To use the GitHub Status check, first, create a pipeline for the repository and build it at least once so that its status is posted to GitHub, thereby making GitHub aware of the pipeline's name._.  
I've triggered and build the `validation` pipeline multiple times already but still do not see the status for `repo1` in `repo1`'s Github - that's my reason for raising this  question.  
_Next, follow GitHub's documentation for configuring protected branches in the repository's settings._.  
The check is missing there, probably because the status was not registered by Github.

Comment: Hi @Styszma, how's this issue? Do you still have this issue? To do a test, could you please try to create a classic pipeline to try again?

Comment: I'm able to see a status check with pipeline just included within repo. No luck with creating them with resources though :( In this case - is there a way to create multiple PR checks from a single pipeline file? E.g. 1 check per step/job?