# How can I get status of an Azure Classic pipeline which is currently running, in GitHub?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

Scenario: Salesforce DevOps

Pipelines are set-up in Azure DevOps and repositories have been migrated to GitHub.

Process:
As soon as someone raises a pull request against master branch, an Azure Pipeline is triggered which validated the committed components against a sandbox. What is the best way where I can see the status of this triggered pipeline in GitHub.
Current setup: After raising PR, every dev has to go to Azure and check whether pipeline is succeeding or not, which in case missed by someone can cause inconsistency in code and overall release process.

From what I've learned, we can get status of completed runs of pipeline from Azure REST API.
I am fairly new to this and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Tried to get status of Azure Pipeline through Git Workflow couldn't figure out exact steps.

Comment: If the webhooks are setup correctly and the pipeline is authenticating to GitHub using the Azure pipelines GitHub app, the status should be reported in the PR status checks itself.

Comment: There is a way to do it with the API as well, ideally from the Azure pipelines side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70041861/736079

Comment: Yes, there is no issue in authentication, as pipeline is successfully triggering after raising a PR. I don't see any success/failure being reported, is there any change I need to do in GitHub to see the pipeline status as status check?
P.S - Enable PR validation in Azure is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DevOps classic pipeline is triggered by the PR on github, you should have enabled  `PR trigger` as below in DevOps pipeline:

[image]

It will report the build result/state to Github PR automatically.

[image]

If you still would like to use rest api to get the DevOps pipeline status, please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831673/14996050).

Edit: Add the detail solution:

1. Check the service connection -> security -> Make sure the pipeline is not restricted.
2. unchecked CI option -> saved -> enabled CI option again, it fixed the status check.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have that option enabled in Azure but don't see pipeline status as checks in github, is there anything I need to do in GitHub to see this?

Comment: `PR validation` on DevOps branch policy is used for DevOps git repo.  To return the status to Github PR, your repo should be on `Github` not DevOps, could you please double check the repo? Then enable the PR trigger as shown above in my 1st screenshot.

Comment: The repo is in GitHub only, can you confirm what are you asking me to double check?

Comment: You have confirmed it's Github repo, thanks.  Next checking is if you have enabled the PR trigger on DevOps CI pipeline as shown in my first screenshot. In addition, you can create a new DevOps CI pipeline(with PR trigger enabled), check if it can return status check to github. If it's OK, on your issue pipeline, delete the service connection from project setting, edit your pipeline to create a new service connection to the github repo.

Comment: I have tried deleting service connection and setting up a new one, didn't work.

Comment: May i know if you tried a new DevOps CI pipeline, if it returns the status check to github successfully? In addition, it's recommended to share your devops pipeline trigger setting screenshot in description for further troubleshooting.

Comment: This issue just got resolved, I changed the service connection security setting and pipelines were restricted. Also, I unchecked CI option -> saved -> tested this by creating dummy PR (didn't work) -> enabled CI option again -> tested again and it worked!

I appreciate your help, thank you!